# Alternating Series test for $\sin(n)/e^n$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image: alternating series test]

I don't think l need to go beyond the last step as it looks like a dead end. Does $\sin(n)$ usually cause the series to diverge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle\left\lvert\frac{\sin n}{e^n}\right\rvert\leqslant e^{-n}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n}$ converges, your series converges absolutely.

But, yes, the sequence $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\sin n}{e^n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}$ is not monotonic.

Comment: Thanks, comparison test is really useful.

Comment: Carlos Santos,  so a non increasing sequence is not a necessary condition for convergence ?

Comment: No, it is not. ${}$

Comment: @AristotleStagiritis $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)/n^2$ is a convergent sequence, and $\left(\dfrac{-1}{n^2}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ is an increasing sequence.

Comment: @Jośe Carlos Santos,  Thank you .